# machine learning forecasting / asking for input parameter

Tags: prediction, forecast

I've been working on a weekly web traffic forecast based on time series. The primary business driver is marketing investment (spend)

I have historical spending data but not future spending data. In this case, how can future web traffic be predicted?

I'd like to have an input request switch where I could change the cost input to see future traffic. (If you spend this much, you will receive these many visits; if you do more, you will get more, and vice versa.)